# Showing the function $A(u)=u(x)$ is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

We consider the Banach space $(C_b (0,1),|| \cdot ||_\infty )$

To show the function $A(u)=u(x)$ is continuous, I have the following proof. 
$$|A(u)| =|u(x)| \leq \sup_{t \in (0,1)} |u(t)|=\|u\|_\infty$$
How does this proof show that $A(u)=u(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: It does not. What is the domain of $A$? What is the topology on the domain? Without knowing this, the question "is $A$ continous" is meaningless.

Comment: But from context, I'm guessing that $u$ belongs to $C_b(X)$, the space of continuous bounded functions on a topological space $X$, under the supremum norm, and $A$ is the linear functional given by evaluation at $x \in X$. In which case, this shows that $A$ is a bounded linear functional of norm at most 1, and hence continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ is the space of bounded functions $(0,1)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, then 
$$A:E\longrightarrow\Bbb R$$
is linear and
$$|A(u-v)| = |u(x)-v(x)|\le\|u-v\|_\infty.$$